# Laravel database, what data type should I use to store an array of IDs?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I'm building an application using Laravel.

In the app there are Users and Hotels, users are assigned a subset of hotels.

I want to store a list of hotel IDs in each User but I'm not sure which data type I should pick from the following list of available data types: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#columns

User migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('role');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The Hotel schema contains a

```
$table->increments('id');
```

field which is the one I want to store.

Which data type would you suggest I use? Or is there a better solution, maybe creating a third table?

Additional information: depending on the user's role, some users(admins) will be able to modify said list of other users.

Comment: hi neviovalsa, welcome to stackoverflow. i do curious why you want to store the list of id into single column instead of experimenting with many-to-many relationships. could you elaborate the reason you did not consider having the third table as an option..?

Comment: I must admit I don't really remember a lot about the database course I had a couple of years ago, and I still don't have much working experience. Anyway, I thought the many-to-many relationships would have been a good solution if I had to go in "both directions" but I always only need to retrieve hotels from users and not the other way around. Isn't it faster to retrieve only an array once?

Thanks for the suggestion anyway, I will probably do it with many-to-many relationships since it seems everybody's solution.

Comment: its fine, and yes many-to-many relationship will have the relationship go both ways. it allows you to retrieve the related hotel rows along with a set of users you want to list in a single sweep through joins. it also ensure referential integrity as you can prevent a hotel from being removed as long as a user assigned to it. there are some pros and cons, and you had to ask yourself do you need all these shiny feature or just want to fetch single user only and then spend yourself querying the database in loop to get the related hotels.. personally, i'd go with third table - its also moresql.

Comment: Reasoning about it I realized it definitely is the better solution for me. So I implemented it using Eloquent, which is also very intuitive.
Thank a lot for the insight again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Many-to-Many relationship. [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

[image]

In your case: A user can belong to multiple hotels and hotels can belong to multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use third table which will contain user id and hotel id.